# Euler's identity in C

Tags: c

Today I was messing around with complex numbers in C and so (naturally) I tried to program in Euler's identity. We all know that e<sup>iπ</sup> = -1 but for some reason C wants to return (positive) 1 -- why is that? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

double main(void){
    double complex exponent = M_PI*I;
    double complex power = exp(exponent);
    printf("%.f\n",power);
    return power;
}
```

Comment: `exp` is for real numbers, you want `cexp` for complex numbers.

Comment: @pat You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @pat, make it an answer with some more info and an example!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complex number is being coerced to a real because `exp` expects a `double` argument.  The coersion discards the imaginary part, and passes only the real part, which is `0`.  Hence, `exp(0) = 1`.

You should use `cexp` instead of `exp`.  `cexp` expects a `double complex`.

You also shouldn't pass a `complex` directly to `printf`, but should print the real and imaginary parts explicitly as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

double main(void){
    double complex exponent = M_PI*I;
    double complex power = cexp(exponent);
    printf("%.f + %.fi\n", creal(power), cimag(power));
    return power;
}
```

Also, returning a `double` from `main` is just plain weird...